# Proper datatypes for Hive DATE and TIMESTAMP for UDF

Tags: java, hive, bigdata

I wrote a new UDF for a Hive project but the return type isn't a DATE object but rather an odd structure.  What is the correct return type?

```
@Description(name = "udf_good_date", value = "_FUNC_(datestring):DATE", extended = "")
@UDFType(deterministic = true, stateful = false)
public class GoodDateAsDateUDF extends UDF {

    public Date evaluate(String a) {
        return Utils.getGoodDate(a);
    }

}
```

Trying it:

```
select default.udf_good_date('10/20/1983);
```

It strangely gives:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
|                                                         _c0                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| {"fasttime":125733600000,"cdate":{"cachedyear":1983,"cachedfixeddatejan1":720259,"cachedfixeddatenextjan1":720624}}  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Comment: Seriously? ....

Comment: I switched to java.sql.Date and more functionality is working. However, java.sql.Timestamp didn't address the Timestamp logic in Impala which can use Hive functions.

Comment: You are returning the result of a function `Utils.getGoodDate` without supplying its code nor its interface nor a relevant link and you seriously expect to get an answer? Thanks god the is Google. what you probably see is the JSON representation of a sun.util.calendar http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/sun/util/calendar/BaseCalendar.java. Check the following source for code examples https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic

Comment: https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFHour.java The URL you gave lead to the answer.

Comment: Yes, this was the point :-) Please add an answer

Comment: Typically you let somebody else write the answer but I took your challenge and put the answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the documentation is lacking with open source projects one needs to visit the actual source code itself to see the true answer. So in regards to the various time-based data types is best to read a representative example in the source code. This particular class illustrates the usage quite well.

https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFHour.java